# Python script starting a binary script

Tags: python, binary

I have a python script making a menu from where to start other python scripts on a xterm window

```
def name(self)
os.system('xterm -bg black -fg white -geometry 150x20 -title name -fa Monospace /path/script.py &')
```

I would like to add 1 more script, but it is binary and it works on specific directory files outputting a txt file

```
Script-bynary /directory/ output.txt
```

Is it possible to make it executable by the phyton menu-script?

I tried

```
def name(self)
os.system('xterm -bg black -fg white -geometry 150x20 -title name -fa Monospace /path/script-bynary /directory/ output.txt &')
```

But it doesn't work

xterm: bad command line option "/path/script-bynary"

Comment: “But it doesn't work” is not helpful.  Help us help you and please provide more (explicit) detail.

Comment: Ok I added the error message

xterm: bad command line option "/path/script-bynary"

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Python. The error you report is from the shell. You would get the same error if you typed the string at a shell prompt. You need to find out how to make `xterm` do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a workaround.
I made a bash script to start the binary one.

```
#!/bin/sh
###this is my bash.script
Script-bynary   /directory/   output.txt
```

and then I have this bash.script into the phyton one

```
os.system('xterm -bg black -fg white -geometry 150x20 -title name -fa Monospace /path/bash.script &')
```

Not the most efficient way, I guess, but works.